# How to make div with text to expand if the text does not fit there

Tags: html, css

My page: [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7C8jd.png)

Html code for message block:

```
<div class="message-body row">
      <div class="text-box ">
        <p>{{message.text}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Css styles:

```
.text-box {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

message-body does not have any styles from css

Comment: Guess you said `expand`, but was thinking to break long words? The case in your screenshot is rare to be.

Comment: @skobaljic to break long word and to expand height of the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.text-box { display: flex; margin-left: 10px; word-break: break-all; }`